# Why was my edit rejected by community with same edit

Tags: discussion, edits

I made an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7715326) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681894/mvc5-asp-net-using-route-attributes-for-actions-in-a-different-area), that was rejected. The [community edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29681894/2) made the same edit plus an additional one that I did not. So why was my edit rejected although it seemingly was a valid one (and got an approve).

EDIT: To clarify: If I was missing some details that I could have edited - why not approve the first edit and make an additional one, instead of completely rejecting it.

Comment: A user chose to reject your edit and improve the original post further.

Comment: It seems that a reviewer didn't like how you left the code split into multiple lines, and decided to reject and replace that with a single-line code tag. Which edit was better is up for debate.

Comment: Might just be that a reviewer clicked the wrong button.

Comment: That's not really encouraging for suggesting edits... The question of why not approving and then improving still stands.

Comment: I just had the exact thing, There was broken code I editted to fix the typos which were breaking the sample code, the edit was rejected but then the changes were put in by a mod, thus making my rejected edit a valid change but notin my name? I'm not to fussed by stats but it seems unfair that I have now got a rejected edit under my name when it was actually used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of editing is to fix *all* the issues in a post, not just a few of them.  As stated in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than
>   you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> ```
> To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> To add related resources or hyperlinks
> ```

You need to fix everything possible in a post.  Since your suggested edits go into a queue where other people have to spend time, it is preferable that we only have to approve one really good and complete edit instead of dozens of little ones.  When I am reviewing edits I have a few choices, one being "Improve edit" where I take what you did and fix up the last little bits.

The tl/dr answer is when you edit you need to do everything you possibly can to make it better, not just some of it or the reviewer *should* improve your edit.

Comment: To quote: `leave the post better than you found it` - it certainly was. So when I don't find every single possible improvement, I get rejected? Strikes me as odd... And I gather "Improve edit" wasn't used in this case?

Comment: @Thaoden Yes, your edit did leave it better than it was.  But like I said, we want you to get it all.  Some people are a bit more stingy about it that others.  As far as if the improve button was used, I can't say.  I could see it showing up as rejected, but I haven't had to deal with my own suggested edit in so long I can't remember.  I know when I improve an edit it shows up immediately and shows that I was the one that made the edit (even if my part of the edit was very minor by comparison).

Comment: @Thaoden "Improve edit" was used, you can see from [your suggested edit rejection](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7715326) that ataravati decided to improve your edit.  When improving edits, there's a checkbox to indicate if the original edit was helpful.  The reviewer in this case decided you didn't fix enough issues and unchecked the box (shows as "Reject and Edit").  The rejection being attributed to Community is a side-effect of the post being de-queued when someone with 3K rep edits the post (instead of waiting for a three-reviewer consensus).