# Edit rejected by Community, but was applied anyway

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I have suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10983268). After submitting it, I noticed that the first word in the title wasn't capitalized, so I did a ninja edit to fix that – which counts as the same edit, if I understand correctly.

The edit was then rejected by Community ("conflicted with subsequent edit"), but was applied anyway, and I can't see another edit on the post.

Did my ninja edit conflict with my first edit?

I've seen a [similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290475/why-was-my-edit-rejected-by-community-with-same-edit), but that was for a case where a reviewer chose "reject and improve".

*Edited to add*: I guess I'm wondering why it looks like the question never looked any different from what it does now, but it did: code was not formatted, for example.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP edited it, and made the same edit you did. The original poster's edits don't show up in the revision history if they happen within 5 minutes of posting.

Comment: @resueman I made about a dozen changes, it's highly unlikely they did exactly the same. And I can't see an "edited" timestamp on the question, which any edited question has, even if the OP edited it.

Comment: @BenjaminW.for the first 5 minutes of the life of a post, there is no "edited" ttimestamp, as long as the edits are from the OP.

Comment: @Patrice So did OP copy-paste my edit?

Comment: I have NO CLUE. maybe he saw it, rolled it in, added his own. I'm just saying that if it's quick enough, it won't necessarily have the timestamp, is all

Comment: @Patrice Okay, got it.

Comment: My experience tells me there is something (perhaps a bug, perhaps not) that causes this to happen.  It [happened to me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141867/suggested-edit-overwritten-by-op-edit) once upon a time with a rejected edit that appears to have been applied (exact match by character) by the OP

Comment: @psubsee2003 Looks very similar to my "thing". Yours was probably after the post was 5 minutes old, as there was a timestamp for the edit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I asked the OP, and it looks as if the following happened (confirmed by suggestions of commenters above – thanks!):

- I made an edit suggestion, and amended the edit (amending not actually important, I think).
- The OP edited the question within the first five minutes as well.
- Our edits got merged, my suggestion was marked rejected, and the post never got a timestamp mentioning an edit because it happened within the first five minutes.

I can't really see what the OP edited, though, as the post looks exactly the way I remember *my* edit.

Comment: Hm, pretty odd flow of events. The only thing I can think of to not blame it on the system is that the OP indeed made an edit that caused yours to be rejected, he somehow saw your edit and decided it was good and applied it himself after the fact - all within 5 minutes. Seems unlikely, but SO is good at producing the unlikely :)

Comment: Or maybe [it was caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

Comment: can you tell me what OP stands for??

Comment: Maybe edit suggestions should cancel the 5 minute grace period, just like comments do. Then this kind of situations would be clearer.

Comment: @reenleedr It's for "original poster".

Comment: @reenleedr Also for "original post". E.g. "The OP stated in their OP that..."