# When OP clicks [edit] while someone suggested an edit, the suggested edit gets used and the edit rejected

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits

This isn't the first time that happens, but it was the most recent one. I made some minimal edits on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38879960/revisions) question (capitalization and some formatting).

However, the OP discarded it and used it as its own, keeping the edit summary. [This is a bug reproduced by Roman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332163/792066):

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> 1. Open some of your own posts and don't touch that page until step 4.
> 2. Someone suggests an edit to your post (in this case I did it myself as *anonymous*).
> 3. Normally, when there is a pending suggested edit to your post, the "edit" link becomes "edit (1)", and clicking it opens a review pop-up
>      (you don't need [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38879960/revisions) to review edits to your
>      own posts). But the link changes only if you (re-)load the page
>      *after* that edit was suggested. So if you just keep the page open and don't refresh it, the link will still be "edit", and clicking it will
>      take you to the editor page.
> 4. Click "edit" - editor opens, but instead of current revision it loads the new (suggested) revision of the post, even with suggested
>      edit summary filled in.
> 5. If you click "Save" without changing anything, an error shows up, saying that your edit is identical to the existing suggested edit. But
>      if you change even one letter, the system happily saves the edit.

Comment: The reject reason was *This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.* so they may not have even seen that you submitted an edit.

Comment: That is interesting.  I wouldn't worry about it though.  rejects due to conflicts do not count against you for bans.

Comment: Well, it's not perfectly identical to [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13295637), since they added a capital `W` for `what`, but other than that the spacing/text changes are identical....  Basically, don't worry about it, seems that this is a new user who is still getting to know what is socially acceptable on the site....

Comment: Even better this way! Now the OP has learned how to improve their post by actually doing it.

Comment: @NathanOliver perhaps one shouldn't worry about it. But this is why I stopped contributing to [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).

Comment: I had exactly the [same problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315223/edit-rejected-by-community-but-was-applied-anyway) - Roman's answer seems to explain what happened.

Comment: YO DAWG, so I heard you like EDITS, so I suggested an edit while were editing so you could go back and edit my edit to your edit!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I just reproduced it on Russian SO (sorry for all the cyrillic, but I wanted to use an account without full editing privileges, just in case): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/99644.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open some of your own posts and don't touch that page until step 4.
2. Someone suggests an edit to your post (in this case I did it myself as *anonymous*).
3. Normally, when there is a pending suggested edit to your post, the "edit" link becomes "edit (1)", and clicking it opens a review pop-up (you don't need [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to review edits to your own posts). But the link changes only if you (re-)load the page *after* that edit was suggested. So if you just keep the page open and don't refresh it, the link will still be "edit", and clicking it will take you to the editor page.
4. Click "edit" - editor opens, but instead of current revision it loads the new (suggested) revision of the post, even with suggested edit summary filled in.
5. If you click "Save" without changing anything, an error shows up, saying that your edit is identical to the existing suggested edit. But if you change even one letter, the system happily saves the edit.

The result: suggested edit becomes rejected by the Community ♦, your edit gets all the changes (plus those you added while editing).

Now you can see how this can happen accidentally, without any bad intentions.

---

I think, if you have full editing privileges, the same can (intentionally) be done with any suggested edit: find an edit, get the post ID from it, then go directly to `/posts/ID/edit`. The editor will kindly load the suggested revision. I didn't test it, but I believe modifying and saving will lead to the same "suggested edit rejected, you own the edit" result.

Comment: Wow, this smells like bug.

Comment: @yellowantphil AFAIK it should load the current version

Comment: That hack with `/posts/ID/edit` [actually works](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13310330).. (sorry to that user for hijacking his edit)

Comment: @yellowantphil It loads the suggested revision.

Comment: @Floern it doesn't load the editor, but a review task.

Answer (score 6):

This [was fixed in October of last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355831/377214).

Basically, this happened because there was only one client-side check to see if there was a pending suggested edit, which occurred when the page was loaded. Thus, if you loaded the page *before* someone suggested an edit, and then proceeded to edit the post yourself, it would just direct you to the post editor since there wasn't a pending edit at the time the page was loaded. Due to [complicated reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/350026/377214), it would load in the pending revision rather than the current (unedited) revision, causing the bug you saw here.

As noted in the above first link, this was resolved: now, whenever anyone with privileges to edit a given post bindingly tries to edit a post with a pending suggested edit, there's now a server-side check to see if there's a pending suggested edit - if so, users will be directed to review that instead. As the check occurs server-side, it works even if there was no pending edit at the time the page was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This really doesn't seem like how it should work. It seems logical that when user1 edits an edit to their own question made by user2 without approving user2's edit first, that upon submitting the edit the system should log in the revision history user2's edit then user1's edit after that as the most current version. The edit wasn't "*rejected*" by user1, it was *used and improved upon*.