# Two identical sets of changes made 10 seconds apart and both edits allowed?

Tags: bug, edits

If you look at the revision history https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41274946/revisions you will see that Benjamin.W and I both made the identical changes (but not identical comments about the changes) at 02:44:59Z (BW) and 02:45:09Z (JL), yet both edits were 'accepted'.  I was expecting to get the 'must be different enough' message when I hit hit Submit, but I didn't get that.

I think it's a non-consequential bug in SO — a curiosity rather than a major problem, but it surprised both me and Benjamin.  I'm recording it here to let the SO staff know what happened.  I won't be surprised if it is marked [status-declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

<sup>*(Winterbash 2016: I already have an 'I Am Your Father' hat for voting on MSO so this isn't hat-hunting.)*</sup>

Comment: Did you also make the same tag change (remove [tag:basic])?

Comment: you can get *'I Am Your Father'* just from voting on meta so no one really suspects your hat hunting with this question

Comment: @BenjaminW. — yes, I made the same textual change (add leading blanks; remove blank lines) and removed the [tag:basic] tag.  All else apart, there is no difference shown between your change and mine.

Comment: I can confirm that I was surprised, too ;) A while back I experienced a [weird editing occurrence](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315223/edit-rejected-by-community-but-was-applied-anyway), too, which was later duped to [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332126/when-op-clicks-edit-while-someone-suggested-an-edit-the-suggested-edit-gets-u).

Comment: i would have though the 10 second gap would have been enough to trigger the *"an edit has been made, please review"* message

Comment: @Memor-X: there was a notification to me of a change (I knew that there'd been another change) — but I hit submit expecting to be told "your change isn't big enough" (or "your change won't be saved unless it is big enough"), and that didn't happen.