# Help me understand why my edit was rejected?

Tags: support, edits

I have read a bunch of "why" posts but they did not seem to help.

- [Why was my edit unanimously rejected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318133/why-was-my-edit-unanimously-rejected)
- [Why was my edit rejected by community with same edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290475/why-was-my-edit-rejected-by-community-with-same-edit)
- [Yet another "Why was my edit rejected?" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306242/yet-another-why-was-my-edit-rejected-question)
- [Why was my edit rejected by community user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280357/why-was-my-edit-rejected-by-community-user)

I believe my edits to a post (first edits ever) correctly clarify the issue that the original poster had as identified in comments of the body of the post from the community.  The original post was of little to no value and I believe the edits add some value in that the identify the actual issue.  Further, I have offered a potential solution in the comments.

My edits were rejected indicating that they "deviate from the original intent", but the original intent was almost meaningless and I feel my edits reflect the actual problem as identified by the original poster in the comments following prompting by the community.

In essence, the OP attempted to identify a symptom (no css styles) when they had not checked the log to uncover the problem (permission denied).  They also included a tag not related to the issue.

I am not sure anyone would ever find a post title "Style Sheet Is Not Picking" as helpful, and I was hoping that my edits would clarify the problem and improve the chance of a solution.

What did I do wrong?  I feel that if what I did is not a valid edit then I don't know what is.

**Issue :** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475328/style-sheet-is-not-picking#comment62773112_37475328

**Rejected Edit :** https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12588788

Comment: It's good that you're trying to help, but, I would have rejected it too if I had the privilege. You removed information that didn't need to be removed.   Specifically, you removed this: *I have checked that the doctype is fine, the links don't have any typos, they all link up correctly in the source.*, why?

Comment: My intent was not to diminish the efforts of the OP to identify the problem, however, now that you have singled out that part I guess it could be viewed as such.  The uri being verified as correct does add something of value and might reinforce the actual permissions issue.  Thanks for your input @ᴉʞuǝ

Comment: Specifically, as to "why".  I initially concluded that information was a false lead and that the existence of the actual problem in the console logs was the correct path to follow.  I can see how verification of the validity of the URIs might add something to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rejection reason was unanimous between all reviewers.

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.

While I wasn't one of the reviewers who rejected it, I agree with their reasoning and here is why.

The title edit seems okay to me but you removed information from the post that didn't need to be removed, specifically you removed the following:

> I have checked that the doctype is fine, the links don't have any
>   typos, they all link up correctly in the source

To me, this is valuable information that should've been left in the post.

Also, you removed information about the it affecting the mobile browsers as well, this too could be seen as valuable information.

When editing, try to preserve as much of the original content as possible.